# add comment form in views

Tags: views, forms, comments

I've created a views from comments. I want to have add comment form at the button of my views (in footer). so I installed "views_php" module and add "Global: PHP" to footer and write this code to print add comment form in footer.

```
$comment = new stdClass;
$comment->nid = $row->nid;
$form = drupal_get_form('comment_form', $comment);
print render($form);
```

but the problem is that I don't have comment_body or any other custom field in the printed form. actually just author, subject and save button.

I tried this code too:

```
print drupal_render(drupal_get_form("comment_form", (object) array('nid' => $data->nid)));
```

or

```
print drupal_render(drupal_get_form("comment_node_news_form", (object) array('nid' => $results[0]->nid)));
```

but none of them worked properly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
$comment = new stdClass;
$comment->nid = $row->nid;
$form = drupal_get_form('comment_form', $comment);
print render($form);
?>
```

Works for me. Make sure that your **Content: Nid** field is **ABOVE** the **Global: PHP** field, otherwise (when it's below it) `$row->nid` is not available as a variable.

[image]

## Update

After reading your Q more carefully, **since you want it in the footer** then you need to specify the node id of the form. (Under what node this comment will be stored) **For Example**: /node/1

```
<?php
$comment = new stdClass;
$comment->nid = 1;
$form = drupal_get_form('comment_form', $comment);
print render($form);
?>
```

If you want /node/5 you change this line to `$comment->nid = 5;`

**OR**

If you want this to be dynamic, the nid to be based on the page you're viewing. Then use

```
<?php
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
$comment = new stdClass;
$comment->nid = $node->nid;
$form = drupal_get_form('comment_form', $comment);
print render($form);
}
?>
```

**Note**: The form will not render/show on views preview, but it will show up when you visit the node.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: that's true appearently but does not work properly. actually when I post the comment redirect to comment/reply/[nid] page and the comment is not posted too.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/204663/rendering-multiple-comment-form-issue