# How to display node in view and allow users add comment?

Tags: views

Is it possible to display a node in a view and allow users to add comments to the node?

I have not been able to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can show node in view and also allow users to add comment. See example below:

1. Create a view normally.
2. Under Format section, change **Show** settings to **Content**
3. Select the view mode as **Full Content** and enable **Display
   Comments**. (Check screenshot below)
4. Click on Apply

[image: View Settings]

[image: View : Row Style settings]

Comment: Any idea why I don't have the "Display comments" option?

Comment: Check if you've comment module installed, if yes, also check if you've comments enabled for that content type

Answer (score 0):

You would need a contrib module to get this functionality, it's called [AJAX Comments](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_comments)

After installing it you will have new views fields available ([screenshot](https://www.drupal.org/files/Screenshot_7_30_13_16_50_0.png)), that will:

a) Allow you to add comments
b) Allow you to display the existing comments

An important point is that following for this [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1793988), AJAX Comments integration with Views adds auto-refresh support in order to display the newly added comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to add comment form to a view

Refer [add comment form in views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/190353/add-comment-form-in-views) @No Sssweat describe it very nicely.

You need to add a global php field and render the comment form.

And display one node you can add filter conditions.