# How to display comment form and comments per node in a view

Tags: 7, views, comments

I am trying to display comments + comment form per node in a view of nodes following [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215561/how-to-display-node-in-view-and-allow-users-add-comment/215565). So I'm trying full content display with row style options, which works perfectly on another site I am working on, but on this one, I don't have the "Display comments" toggle box[image]

So I have reinstall the site and disable every thing I could : contrib modules / themes and templates / custom code / libraries / fields & comment fields / all content types trying with new ones / uninstall & reinstall comment modules / combination of permissions for all/just admin in view-post-skip options. Still nothing.

Anyone has seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you've comment module installed, if yes, also check if you've comments enabled for that content type

Comment: That's the first thing I did, I forgot to mention